# neo4j simple query on large database

Tags: optimization, neo4j, out-of-memory, cypher

Could someone explain this to me:

On the [Neo4j website](https://neo4j.com/blog/tuning-cypher-queries) it recommends using node labels when searching

However when I do this on a large database (2 million nodes):

```
MATCH p = (n:Foo)-[r:Bar]->(m:Foo)<-[s:Bar]-(o:Foo) RETURN p LIMIT 1
```

It results in a horrible breadth first search that compares over a billon objects, and the function never returns.

[image: BFS]

The label-less equivalent on the other hand completes in less than a seconds.

```
MATCH p = (n)-[r:Bar]->(m)<-[s:Bar]-(o) RETURN p LIMIT 1
```

￼
[image: DFS]

Is there any way to make the labelled version perform the same type of search?

Comment: What version of neo4j are you using?

Comment: Did you try specifying singly directed relationships?

Comment: yes, I've put this in the description now, version 3.0.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on your data, but you could try breaking down that query into parts, working toward your final result.

```
MATCH (m:Foo)
WHERE SIZE( (m)<-[:Bar]-(:Foo) ) > 1
WITH m LIMIT 1
MATCH p = (n:Foo)-[r:Bar]->(m)<-[s:Bar]-(o:Foo) 
RETURN p LIMIT 1
```

It may also be worth checking if the planner will execute the query differently if we start from the center :Foo node in the pattern rather than what it's doing now, which is expanding from every possible end node of the pattern then running the hash join to find nodes in the middle.

```
MATCH (m:Foo)
WITH m
MATCH p = (n:Foo)-[r:Bar]->(m)<-[s:Bar]-(o:Foo) 
RETURN p LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Excellent, your first suggestion hits the nail on the head (the second gives the slow hash-join, I guess it works out it's equivalent)